# How does UITabBarController work?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a custom thing that should work similarly to UITabBarController—a UIViewController that manages sub-ViewControllers. The parent UIViewController should manage adding and removing the views of the child UIViewControllers.

It seems if I'm doing things this way I need to call `[UIViewController viewWillAppear]` and friends manually. Is this the case? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? Why not use UITabBarController?

Anyway... I would try with something like this

```
- (void) selectViewControllerAtIndex:(int)index {
    [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.selectedVCIndex].view removeFromSuperview];
    self.selectedVCIndex = index;
    [self.view addSubView:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index].view];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Never tried it, though.

Comment: This code might explode!  I think you need `[self.view addSubView:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index]].view`

Comment: ... what does UITableViewController have to do with anything? I want to make a custom tab bar.

Comment: Ups, I shoud have said UITabBarController... Anyway, the code remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to create a singleton with these methods:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

    UIViewController *currentVC;

}

-(void) destroyCurrent;
-(void) switchToViewController: (int) controller;

-(void) switchToViewController: (int) controller {

    [self destroyCurrent];

    switch (controller) {
        case 0:
            MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
            currentVC = viewController;
            break;
        //case 1: ...
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:currentVC.view];
}

-(void) destroyCurrent {

    if (currentVC) {
        [currentVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [currentVC release];
        currentVC = nil;
    }
}
```

where by calling `switchToViewController: (int) controller` you change the view controllers.

Comment: This doesn't help with calling methods like `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Yes, but you can just move what you need in `viewWillAppear` to init. Or add a `[currentVC performSelector: @selector(viewWillAppear:)];`  line after `[self.view addSubview:currentVC.view];`. Adding `[currentVC performSelector: @selector(viewWillDisappear:)];` before "destroying" the view will also work.

Comment: Why `performSelector:` instead of just calling the selector?

Comment: I usually do this because you can check if an object responds to selector before calling it to perform one. Also, in this particular case I'm always using some kind of transitions between views, so I need a method for preforming something after delay.